# When checking out a repo on Github Actions workflow, how do I pass in a deploy key for a private submodule but not the repo itself?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, git-submodules, build-server

When checking out a repo on Github Actions workflow, how do I pass in a key for a private submodule but not the repo itself? This is currently how I am doing it: The `ACCESS_KEY` is the private key of a deploy key which is stored in the main repo. That key should only apply to the submodule and not the repo itself though. How can I force that functionality? Currenly I get an error because it is trying to use the SSH key to checkout the main repo.

```yaml
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
      submodules: 'true'
      ssh-key:  ${{ secrets.ACCESS_KEY }}
```

Comment: @Konstantin Tarkus, do you know?

Answer (score 1):

Specify token parameter with a PAT from e.g. a machine user or just your personal user.

```
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      submodules: recursive
      token: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN_FOR_SUBMODULES }}
```

Comment: I don't want to use a personal access token, because this is a workflow that is going to run anytime anyone pushes to the repo. What is a machine user? Is that something I can create on Github?

Comment: Machine user is just a dedicated GitHub user, used as a service account, so the token is not bound to your account. Another way to still use a token, is to generate a deploy key. This key is bound to the repo and can be generated from repo -> Settings -> Deploy Keys. Maybe a better fit.

Comment: I've tried the deploy key. But when I use it, it tries to use it, not only for the submodule, but also the repo as well, which causes a failure. Do you have a way around this? Basically, I need the deploy key to be ONLY for the submodule and ${{github.token}} to be used for the repo itself